# Alfresco Share Customization: Display author name instead of modified by

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I wanted to customize the metadata displayed for documents to show the name of the author instead of the 'modified by' information. Here is what I put into `share-config-custom.xml`

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
    <metadata-templates>
        <template id="customTemplate">
            <line index="10" id="author">{author}</line>
        </template>
    </metadata-templates>
</config>
```

But share doesn't respect this and default meta-data is rendered. However, if I were to edit the main config file: `share-documentlibrary-config.xml`; then the author's name is displayed. Obviously, I don't want to be editing the core files; so I would really appreciate any feedback on what the mistake in my code is?

Also, here are some more n00b questions

1) If I were to add some text to indicate the field, say: Author: ${author}, then it is displayed in the reverse order as- 'XYZName Author: ' Suggestions on why this is happening.

2) say I wanted this line to be not displayed at all if the author name is blank; how would I go about doing it? From MikeH's blog post, I realize I might need to write a custom evaluator to make this happen; but my knowledge ends there; is there a working sequence of steps that I can first try and build upon.

3) Is it possible to have different meta-data displayed for spaces and content? If possible, any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Could you please provide the version of Alfresco you're using and the link to the article you mention?

Comment: I am using Alfresco 4.0.d community and [here](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/mikeh/2011/09/26/share-document-library-extensions-in-v4-0/) is the link to the article. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got a response to the questions 1-3 on the Alfresco community forums [here](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=43714&p=128389#p128211). I have put up a possible reason for share not using the configuration under Tahir's answer below.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Blog of Mike Hatfield](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/mikeh/2011/09/26/share-document-library-extensions-in-v4-0/) You need to put the changes in share-documentlibrary-config.xml. Can't you create this file in the web-extension folder? I guess it should be picked up.

If not, try to package it in a *.jar file, it might be picked up then.

If that still doesn't work, locate the -context file, I guess it's slingshot-documentlibrary-context.xml. Here it should load the above config file. Add an override, like the share-config-custom.xml and name it share-documentlibrary-config-custom.xml which looks in the web-extension folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response; there are two share-config-custom.xml file; when I moved it to the one in the webapps/share/.. layout; things seem to be working. AFAIK, I would stay away from editing share-documentlibrary-config.xml since it has a number of share configurations.

Answer (score 0):

According to your "if I were to edit the main config file: share-documentlibrary-config.xml; then the author's name is displayed.", then you can write these code in share-config-custom.xml by adding replace="true" in config tag like this. You should copy all text within config to your share-config-custom.xml and modifying your own.

```
    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary" replace="true">
    ...............................
    ...............................
        <metadata-templates>
            <template id="customTemplate">
                <line index="10" id="author">{author}</line>
            </template>
        </metadata-templates>
    ...............................

    </config>
```